# Enable HTTPS for Azure cloud service (Virtual Machine running Linux Server)

Tags: linux, azure, ssl, https

I'm trying to enable HTTPS on my Azure cloud service.
It doesn't belong to azurewebsites.
I'm using a self-signed certificate, already generated.
Following this [guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate-portal/) I encounter a problem: I'm not able to access to the .csdef file to modify WebRole section to create a proper endpoint as described in the guide.

I would like to know if there's any method to enable HTTPS using self-signed certificates through the Azure Portal.

I tried to open the 443 port naming the endpoint HTTPS, using TCP protocol; unfortunately I notice that modifying the .csdef file instead it's possible to apply the https protocol directly.

Can you help me? I'm kind of stuck at the moment.

Comment: It is not clear for me - what do you mean "following ... i am not able to access"? What is the reason why you can not do that manually as described and upload it? I think that there is no way to do the whole process on the portal.

Comment: @AlexandrBelotserkovskiy At the moment I'm not able to use Visual Studio because I don't have my Windows laptop with me. So since I can use only my Linux machine I wanted to know if I could do everything from the portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Service configuration file** and **Service package** were placed in storage. With [Get Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj154121.aspx) (REST API) you can retrieve cloud service package that used for deployment before.

Also here is a more detailed article: [Download Microsoft Azure Cloud Service Package files](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/jaredjohnson/2014/11/10/download-microsoft-azure-cloud-service-package-files), hope it do help.

Comment: Is it possible to update the **Service configuration file** and the **Service package** deploying a modified package that has been retrieved with this API?

Comment: You could use https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-model-and-package/#cspkg to create Service package which is available in Azure SDK. And also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2011/12/11/exploring-windows-azure-package-contents/ says the .CSPKG is a ZIP file.